# How to repaint a Word 2003 menubar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2003 .dot template that changes its menu based on the condition of the active document.
The `DocumentChange`, `DocumentOpen` and `NewDocument` events of `Word.Application` trigger setting the `.Visible` and `.Enabled` properties of CommandBarButton controls.

On switching active documents, controls exposed by changing the `Visible` property display correctly, but text buttons which have been enabled/disabled do not change appearance.  You can show enabled controls by hovering over them, but the disabled ones do not repaint until you place a window in front.

Is there a simple way to send a repaint message to the menubar, to simulate hiding and exposing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are playing with the visible & enabled properties of the controls. But did you try to hide/unhide the whole commandbar to refresh it?

```
application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.visible = false
application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.visible = true
```